# asp.net gridview. use DeleteCommand as updatecommand?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$    ConnectionStrings:DbConnection %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [userid],[loginid], [password], [contactname], [phone], [zip], [state], [city], [address], [companyid], [email] FROM [users] where [active]=1"
    UpdateCommand="Update [users] set [loginid]=@loginid, [password]=@password, [contactname]=@contactname, [phone]=@phone, [zip]=@zip, [state]=@state, [city]=@city, [address]=@address, [companyid]=@companyid, [email]=@email where [userid]=@userid"
    DeleteCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[users] SET     [active] = 0 WHERE userid=@userid">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Hi I am trying tutorials and they have a basic out of the box gridview  commands autogenerateDelete and autogenerateEdit.

my questions are

1. I like the edit/update/cancel buttons. Is there a way that I do not need to select my primary key (userid)to be shown on the gridview in order for these commands to work?
2. I want to use the autogenerateDelete button as  an update button but it is not working. I just want to set active =0 instead of actually deleting the row is this possible?Error that I get "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@userid"."

Comment: You're not declaring the parameters - see [Using Parameters with the SqlDataSource Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @stuartd Why does my UPDATE not require myuserid=@userid to be declared  but my Delete does?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating. It may help...